# Need help in execute immediate update query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this query and it's not updating into the database. The given "where" clause is valid. When I run the query independently, it works fine but in this Procedure it's not working. There is no exception or no error. Could you guys help me in figuring out where the problem is?

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  ' || dest || ' SET COUNTRY_CODE = :v1 WHERE col_id = :v2'
          USING l_vc_CountryCode, l_vc_ColId;

if SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN
          inserts := inserts + 1;
          counter := counter + 1;
          IF counter > 500 THEN
            counter := 0;
            COMMIT;
          END IF;
        END IF;
```

I didn't write the commit code before. Just to clarity.

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing your question title so it is less generic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that col_id is the primary key. So in the update statement

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  ' || dest || ' SET COUNTRY_CODE = :v1 WHERE col_id = :v2'
          USING l_vc_CountryCode, l_vc_ColId;
```

you are always updating at most one row and thus the condition

```
SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1
```

is never true ( 1 is not > 1 )

So if you don't have any other commit statement in your procedure, you will never commit those updates.

By the way: what is the purpose of this

```
if SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN
          inserts := inserts + 1;
          counter := counter + 1;
          IF counter > 500 THEN
            counter := 0;
            COMMIT;
          END IF;
        END IF;
```

why don't you just commit at the end of your work?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works okay (ie updates the row).
I suspect your error is elsewhere.

For example, if you don't initialise COUNTER, the increment will still leave it as null and it will never commit.

Or, l_vc_ColId may be the wrong datatype and suffering from an invalid conversion.

```
declare
  v_emp_id number := 7839;
  v_name varchar2(4) := 'DING';
  v_tab varchar2(3) := 'EMP';
begin
  execute immediate 'update '||v_tab||
                    ' set ename = :v_name Where empno = :v_emp_id'
     using v_name, v_emp_id;
  dbms_output.put_line('C:'||sql%rowcount);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to reconsider your design if your using dynamic sql to change the "dest" table in thousands of updates.

Much better to know your dest and use bind variables for the where conditions.  then you can commit every x rows using mod or similar:

```
if (mod(v_ctr, 1000) = 0) then
  commit;
end if;
```

But for your example, Marcin is correct, if you are updating only 1 row at a time, then

```
if SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1
```

will never be true;

EDIT:
A simple example knowing your "dest" table:

```
declare

  cursor sel_cur is
  select col1, col2, from sourceTable where col3 = 'X';

  v_ctr pls_integer := 0;

begin
  for rec in sel_cur
  loop
    v_ctr := v_ctr + 1;

    -- implicit bind variables used
    update destTable
    set col1 = rec.col1,
        col2 = rec.col2
    where col3 = 'Z';

    if (mod(v_ctr, 1000) = 0) then
      commit;
    end if;

  end loop;

exception
  when others then rollback;
  raise;
end;
```

If using dynamic SQL, a simple example using explicit bind variables (USING clause) from Oracle docs:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raise_emp_salary (column_value NUMBER, 
                             emp_column VARCHAR2, amount NUMBER) IS
   v_column VARCHAR2(30);
   sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
-- determine if a valid column name has been given as input
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO v_column FROM USER_TAB_COLS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES' AND COLUMN_NAME = emp_column;
  sql_stmt := 'UPDATE employees SET salary = salary + :1 WHERE ' 
               || v_column || ' = :2';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING amount, column_value;
  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salaries have been updated for: ' || emp_column 
                        || ' = ' || column_value);
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Invalid Column: ' || emp_column);
END raise_emp_salary;
/
```

For more reading, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#LNPLS001).

Hope this helps, happy coding

Comment: I don't have any idea about PLSQL. That was a simple changed assigned to me. so i looked for SQL%ROWCOUNT and someone suggested that use this condition to commit. Which i believe is wrong. I will double check it and accept Marcin answer but could you explain me what is ***(mod(v_ctr,1000) = 0)*** statement doing?

Comment: mod is short for modulus.  v_ctr is a simple counter inside a for loop, incremented on each pass through the loop.  mod(v_ctr, 1000) = 0 simply says once you hit pass 1000 through the loop, then do something (in this case, commit your work).

Answer (score 0):

Execute immediate needs explicit commit.  I guess you checked that ?

Comment: yes, its already there. here is my updated code. the SQL%ROWCOUNT is always 0 or less than 1 .. :s

Comment: I had to start with that.  You have more than 500 rows ? Also I would have written > 0 not 1 (didn't understand you comment i guess).

Comment: I understand this snippet lives in a loop.  At the end of that loop you should do something like if inserts > 0 commit for the remaining part of the updated rows.  Do you also have that commit as well ?